# Ignore or handle unimportant keys in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have a JSON object coming from an API that looks something like:

```
{
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Some Post"
    },
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

But when the Ember app makes the request to the API (using the RESTAdapter), Ember gives me this error:

```
Your server returned a hash with the key version but you have no mapping for it.
```

Is there a way to handle, or otherwise ignore that key? [The documentation explains how to handle an irregular key in the object](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_underscored-attribute-names), but I can't find anything about keys *outside* of the object. It seems like this would be a pretty common scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough I have to admit that this is indeed a pretty common use case that the JSON response will include extra keys outside the main object, lamentably in ember-data as for now only two extra keys are supported, this are `meta` and `since` which are allowed by the `RESTSerializer`.

> Is there a way to handle, or otherwise ignore that key?

So the answer will be, if you can't change your backend to not include this extra keys it will not work as you already saw.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is very unfortunate for me! But thank you for the answer :) I hope to see support for this in a future release of Ember-Data.